# Jenkins access logs for debugging issues

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying out jenkins for first time. Have some exp with Hudson.

I am trying to debug a remote job started from an application. I am not even sure if the request made it to the jenkins master and I don't see the job being queued in the UI.

Where is the jenkins access log found so I can look if the server was even hit with the request? I have jenkins installed on mac.

Also in hudson world I used to look at the following to debug any issues. Would be great if someone can point to relevant logs for jenkins if they are different.

- catalina.out
- localhost-YYYY-MM-DD.log
- access-YYYY-MM-DD.log
- access.log

Thanks so much.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe access logs are enabled by default, but you can turn them on. [Here's the documentations](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Access+Logging) for doing so.

> **Steps to enable an access log**
>
> For Ubuntu:
>
> Add these lines to /etc/default/jenkins above JENKINS_ARGS:
>
> Enable access log
>
> JENKINS_ACCESSLOG="--accessLoggerClassName=winstone.accesslog.SimpleAccessLogger --simpleAccessLogger.format=combined --simpleAccessLogger.file=/var/log/jenkins/access.log"
>
> Edit /etc/default/jenkins and add  $JENKINS_ACCESSLOG to JENKINS_ARGS
>
> Enable log rotation: edit /etc/logrotate.d/jenkins and change /var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log to /var/log/jenkins/*.log

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @TheEllis' answer:

For Jenkins Windows service, you may have to update `jenkins.xml` located in the installation / home folder.

Add `--accessLoggerClassName=winstone.accesslog.SimpleAccessLogger --simpleAccessLogger.format=combined --simpleAccessLogger.file=%BASE%/logs/access.log` at the end within the `<arguments>` block.

The updated `Jenkins.xml` file should look like below:

```
<service>
  <id>jenkins</id>
  <name>Jenkins</name>
  <description>This service runs Jenkins continuous integration system.</description>
  <env name="JENKINS_HOME" value="%BASE%"/>
  <executable>%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java</executable>

  <arguments>-Xrs -Xmx3072m -Dhudson.lifecycle=hudson.lifecycle.WindowsServiceLifecycle -jar "%BASE%\jenkins.war" --httpPort=8080 --webroot="%BASE%\war" --accessLoggerClassName=winstone.accesslog.SimpleAccessLogger --simpleAccessLogger.format=combined --simpleAccessLogger.file="%BASE%/logs/access.log"</arguments>

  <logmode>rotate</logmode>
  <onfailure action="restart" />
</service>
```